# How to add the % symbol directly after a variable call in Obj C?

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I have a program that calculates some user input, and I would like to show it as a percent. I just need to know how to put the '%' symbol in my code without it crashing on me.

Using,

```
lblUserTypedName.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%2.1f", ultimate_risk];
```

Prints out a number, like 18.4. I would like for it to print out 18.4%. I've tried the following

```
lblUserTypedName.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%2.1f%", ultimate_risk];
```

and it doesn't print the '%' symbol. I've tried the following.

```
lblUserTypedName.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%2.1f\%\", ultimate_risk];
```

with no luck.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use "%%" to print a single "%". That is,

```
lblUserTypedName.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%2.1f%%", ultimate_risk];
```

Answer (score 1):

Search the docs in Xcode for "String format specifiers".  You'll find a full list of them there.